# Unable to implement security to SSAS Cube when connecting through Excel

Tags: ssas, excel-2010, roles

Users connects to Cube data through Excel. but they need role level security.

So, we are hiding a measure for a role. When connecting to Excel,It is throwing error.

Here is the way that we are hiding a measure to a role.

BIDS -> Solution Explorer -> Roles -> Dimension data ->Select MeasuresDimension--> Unselecting the measures which should not be displayed.I am unselecting [mymeasure].

And I am connecting to the cube data through Excel. But I am getting error " The member [mymeasure] was not found in the cube when the String [measures].[mymeasure], was parsed"

Please help.

Comment: Do you connect from a blank Excel sheet or from one that was connected to the cube before the measure was removed from the users role? Do you connect directly to the cube or via http?

Comment: Hi I am connecting to a blank excel and connecting directly to the cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are unfortunately prompted in Excel because of calculated members exists that uses measures that the user has no authorization on.

To 'catch' the error you will have to adapt your MDX script

Check Jorg Klein's blog, he knows how to solve this stuff:
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2013/02/18/implement-ssas-md-cell-security-using-dimension-security-with-blazing-performance.aspx

Solution and examples are listed there.